# Grails: How to pass a parameter to a template from a custom taglib?

Tags: templates, grails, parameters

I have a custom tag library which is trying to render a certain template.

```
def ifRegistered = {attrs ->
    ....
    if(!output) {
        out << render(template: 'register', model: "[param:1]")
    }
    else {
        out << render(template: 'cancel')
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass a parameter from my tag to my template and it is not working. 
This is how I try to read my parameter in my template _register.gsp.

```
 ${param}
```

I am getting a null value here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taglibs are directly written in groovy. There is no need to use a string to describe a model:

```
out << render(template: 'register', model: [param:1]) // a map is passed as model instead of a string
```

Comment: Aaahh, I was looking for hours for this. I copied a `<g:render template="/template/fieldError" model="[field: 'name']"/>` tag from a gsp to `g.render(...)` inside a custom tag and did not remove the quotes.  In a gsp it has to have quote, in the custom tag it does not.